# Magento 2 Rest API: create / update order,customer information

Tags: magento2, customer, api, rest-api

I want to create and update customers, order in Magento-2. But I am facing problem in **how to pass data to create customer**. Can anyone give me an example for this?

I passed data like:

```
$cusData = "rest/V1/customers/{'customers': {'customer':{'email':'testmy@test.com','firstname':'Jhon','lastname':'test'}}}";

$cusMethod = 'PUT';

$cusJsonData = getData($token,$cusData,$cusMethod);

function getData($token,$data,$method)
{
    try{
        $requestUrl = BASEURL.$data;
        $ch = curl_init($requestUrl);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));
        return curl_exec($ch);
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Create New Customer**

```
    $userData = array("username" => "admin", "password" => "admin123");
    $ch = curl_init("http://magento213/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($userData));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-Lenght: " . strlen(json_encode($userData))));

    $token = curl_exec($ch);


    $customerData = [
        'customer' => [
            "email" => "user@example.com",
            "firstname" => "John",
            "lastname" => "Doe",
            "storeId" => 1,
            "websiteId" => 1
        ],
        "password" => "Demo1234"
    ];

    $ch = curl_init("http://magento213/index.php/rest/V1/customers");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($customerData));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    $result = json_decode($result, 1);
    echo '<pre>';print_r($result);
```

**For Update Customer**

```
$customerData = [
    'customer' => [
        'id' => 10,
        "email" => "user@example.com",
        "firstname" => "John2",
        "lastname" => "Doe2",
        "storeId" => 1,
        "websiteId" => 1
    ],
    "password" => "Demo1234"
];

$ch = curl_init("http://magento213/index.php/rest/V1/customers/10");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($customerData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

$result = json_decode($result, 1);
echo '<pre>';print_r($result);
```

[API LIST](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/rest/list.html)
[Create a customer account](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/tutorials/orders/order-create-customer.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can find examples and detailed informations in the official documentation: http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index_20.html#/

For customer creation go to the `customerCustomerRepositoryV1` entry and choose the `PUT` entries for customer creation